# Make objects flip Box2D?

Tags: libgdx, physics, box2d

I'm working on a shooter, platformer and everything is going okay so far, but I want to make some enemies that fly over top of the player and swoop around him. How can I make them fly? I've seen people suggest to change the world Gravity but that'd mess up the player. What's the best solution?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the right combination of forces through applyForceToCenter()

Answer (score 0):

You can change the gravity for a singe body using

```
body.setGravityScale(0);
```

You could then move the bodies with ApplyForce or directly change their position.

Comment: `LibGDX`, not `Unity`!

Comment: This is available in LibGdx 
[libgdx docs](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Body.html#setGravityScale-float-)

Comment: If so, change the `->` to `.`! :)